# Mouseleave из 2 div-ов сразу - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Когда я навожу на определенный объект появляется еще один объект, пусть это будут дивы.
Они находятся рядом друг с другом, и теперь 2-ому диву нужно пропасть, если мышка вышла и из первого дива, и из 2-го дива одновременно. Как это сделать, желательно с jq.

Общий пример (при наведении на цифры появляется табличка, ее нужно убрать, если мышка выходит из ее зоны, и зоны цифр) (ссылка на codepen):
codepen.io/Radmir2015/pen/xdXNQV?editors=1010

Второй вопрос про тот же проект и касается CSS:
У меня в таблице в ячейках лежит h2. h2 занимают не всю область из td. Как сделать при :hover именно на h2, background-color менялся у td, в котором произошел hover на h2?

Comment: Код в студию!..

Comment: @AGS17 я еще не придумал как это сделать, у меня есть целый проект на codepen.io/Radmir2015/pen/xdXNQV
Когда навожу на цифру, он отображает панель, я там должен выбрать число, в jq вроде можно отследить только из одного селектора выход мышки. Нужно придумать какой-то объединяющий селектор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой jq, это же простейший css... По второму вопросу - на чистом css вы так не сделаете, ибо наследование.

```css
div {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   border: 1px solid white;
   color: white;
   line-height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 300%;
}
.second {
   display: none;
}
.second:hover,
.first:hover ~ .second {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">.first</div>
<div class="second">.second</div>
```

Comment: А как-то с помощью jq и mouseleave можно сделать?, просто я все в jq пытаюсь сделать. Появляется второй див именно по центру, где курсор, в чистом css будет сложно сделать.